# Microsoft Kinect V1 Country List

Tags: kinect

what is the difference in the different country versions of the kinect for windows. There are versions like L6M-00002 for UK/Ireland only. Does this mean, it is a different power plug? Or is it a real different version of the device.

Answer (score 0):

No the functionality is still the same and only the power source would be different. Also there might be some other selling regulations too.